# Handling lots of commands in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, icommand

I'm looking for advice on handle a growing number of commands in a wpf mvvm project.

My viewmodels are collecting a good number of them, and I feel like before the project is matured I need to do something better to handle them.  Right now all my commands are just listed as properties in my viewmodels, and either loaded in the constructor of the VM, or lazy loaded.

And if it matters I'm using MVVM Light's RelayCommand implementation of ICommand.

I've seen on a larger open source project putting them in collections, and grouping those collections into more collections...that all seemed really messy to me, but the context was a little different, as all those commands were binding to menus.  I don't have a typical drop down menu in this application, but I do use many different context menus/buttons.

Anyways, what are some ideas on handling commands, from both a code readability/maintainability as well as functional perspective?

Comment: When I have lots of commands, I have placed them in a partial class of the VM called XXXXCommanding, where XXXX is the name of the VM.  I don't go along with placing them in collections however.  If I need to iterate all the commands, I'll use reflection.

Comment: Have you considered that your ViewModels might be doing to much work?

Comment: I'm with @CodeMonkey on this one. Misusing partial classes to split your giant class across multiple individual files is just hiding the problem.

Comment: I agree, a partial class would help readability in the short term, but if a new developer was added to the project...well if it was me I'd be saying WTF.  Of course @Gayot Fow, that's not to say it's bad advice...definately an option I hadn't considered.  On the other hand, I don't think it's rare for an application to have many commands, so I don't quite think that my viewmodels are overextended.

Comment: @CodeMonkey where does one draw the line?  The logic has to exist somewhere...following the pattern (to my understanding) it has to exist in the viewmodels...so is your suggestion more view models?

Comment: @MatthewHilgenfeld it depends :) I can't really tell you where the line is without specifics. But how many commands are we talking? Also is your issue that the command logic takes up alot of space in the viewmodel or simply that you have 200 lines of `public ICommand FooCommand {get;set;}`

Comment: Yeah, mostly the latter...lots of property declarations like that.  It may be that this is just as good as it gets.  I've even resorted to using some Regions...which typically annoys me to death, so was hoping there was some greater revelation out there...

Comment: @MatthewHilgenfeld, on my own behalf, I should also add that I have used the CommandParameter to compress command families into a single command.  It reduces four navigation commands to a single command, reduces 8 search commands to a single command, and so on.  I cannot vouch for the worthiness of this technique, but command families definitely simplifies the code base if that's your objective.

Comment: Also, if you find yourself doing a lot of "Toolbar"-like UIs and their respective Commands (think for example a CRUD screen with New, Edit, Save, Cancel, Delete, etc). Consider using an `ObservableCollection<ICommand>` and implementing the UI as an `ItemsControl` with an ItemTemplate containing buttons. That's what I usually do when there's "groups" of commands.

Comment: Can you give us example of such ViewModel and its *many* commands (i.e. what sort of commands)? I'm asking because the only times I've seen more than 3-4 commands per view model is when it was an anti-pattern, namely something resembling *god object*. Maybe your design can be improved.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input...I've revisited my ViewModels and made sure the commands are appropriate for the context of the viewmodel.  I appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/morgan/archive/2010/06/24/simplifying-commands-in-mvvm-and-wpf.aspx) show you how to create dynamic properties for exposing your custom commands. You can mix this with reflection in order to handle a lot of commands.

Create a custom attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class CommandClassAttribute : Attribute
{
    readonly string commandName;

    public CommandClassAttribute(string commandName)
    {
        this.commandName = commandName;
    }

    public string CommandName
    {
        get { return commandName; }
    }
}
```

Then mark all your command with it:

```
[CommandClass("New")]
public class NewCommand : ICommand
{
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("New");
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

You can then load all commands at application startup:

```
readonly Dictionary<string, ICommand> commands = new Dictionary<string, ICommand>();

void LoadCommands()
{
    Type[] types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetExportedTypes();
    var iCommandInterface = typeof(ICommand);
    foreach (Type type in types)
    {
        object[] attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CommandClassAttribute), false);
        if (attributes.Length == 0) continue;
        if (iCommandInterface.IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            string commandName = ((CommandClassAttribute)attributes[0]).CommandName;
            commands.Add(commandName, (ICommand)Activator.CreateInstance(type));
        }
    }
}
```

This architecture can be easily extended to support defining commands in plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Meh... if it bothers you to look at them, then put them in a #region and collapse the region. The guy who suggested putting them in a dictionary, so you only have one property that seems like a maintenance headache to me... and the XAML binding gets messy.

Answer (score 0):

> Right now all my commands are just listed as properties in my viewmodels, and either loaded in the constructor of the VM, or lazy loaded.

Instead of making a distinct property for each command in the `ViewModel`, try making a single collection property `Commands` to hold all commands in the `ViewModel`.

This way you simply create and add all the commands to the `Commands` collection in the `ViewModel` constructor or even from a factory method outside the `ViewModel` constructor.

> Anyways, what are some ideas on handling commands, from both a code readability/maintainability as well as functional perspective?

1. 95% of cases there is no need to differentiate between commands in the `ViewModel`.
2. It's easier to maintain one collection property that to maintain lots of properties in the `ViewModel`.
3. `Commands` collection can be easily made composite and mapped to a toolbar or a hierarchical context menu.
4. The ability to add commands to `ViewModel` without changing the existing class or subclassing is really great.